# Getting data from another controller

Tags: angularjs

I have one controller.

```
app.controller('first',['$scope','scopeService', function ($scope,scopeService){

$scope.initialize = function()
{
    scopeService.store('value', $scope);
}
```

}]);

My second controller is

```
app.controller('second',['$scope','scopeService', function ($scope,scopeService){

$scope.initialize = function()
{
    scopeService.get('value', $scope);
}
```

}]);

But my second controller is loaded before first so i am getting value as undefined..

Comment: But my second controller is loaded before first // what do you mean by this? Which page has first controller should be loaded first, because that where you are saving the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data between the controller in two different ways. One way is to use a service to get and store data. Then both controllers can get the data from the service itself. Services are singleton so if it stores data once in its variable then another controller can get is as well.

Another way is to use Angular events. You can emit an event from your second controller and have the first controller listen for the event.

Example code, emit event:

```
$scope.$emit('event-name', {data: someDate});
```

Then receive the event using $rootScope:

```
$rootScope.$on('event-name', function (event, data) {
    //do something with data
});
```

In your case, you should emit the event when your controller receives the data. Then the first controller listening to this event will get the data as well.

Comment: One small thing to add. $emit sends message to the parent scope. $broadcast sends it to the children. You can also send messages on $rootScope and ussually you want to listen on the controller $scope, not on $rootscope

Comment: Yes, correct. $rootScope should only be used when transferring data between unrelated controllers (when they don't have any relation to each other).